# Vue JS setting image through file uploader on v-model applies empty object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I'm using Vue JS 2 to create an image uploader. My input has a `change` function which runs a function and sets my file on `v-model` property.

When I `console.log` my data, all what's set is an empty object rather than the image, this is also causing my Vee Validate rule to fail as it thinks it's empty.

What am I missing?

My HTML for uploading a logo

```html
<validation-observer ref="brandCreationForm" v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
  <form class="space-y-6" @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit(create)">
    <validation-observer :key="1" class="space-y-6">

      <pre>
        {{ form }}
      </pre>

      <div>
        <validation-provider
          name="brand"
          rules="required"
          v-slot="{ errors, classes }"
        >
          <label for="brand" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 mb-2">Brand name</label>
          <div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm">
            <input v-model="form.brand" type="text" name="brand" id="brand" :class="classes" class="focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 block w-full py-3 px-4 sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md" placeholder="my brand name">
          </div>
          <span class="text-xs text-red-500">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
        </validation-provider>
      </div>

      <section v-if="form.brand != '' && form.url != ''" class="space-y-6 pl-6">
        <div>
          <validation-provider
            name="brand_logo"
            rules="mimes:image/jpeg,image/png"
            v-slot="{ errors, classes, validate }"
          >
            <label for="brand_logo" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 mb-2">
              Brand logo <em>(PNG or JPG)</em>
            </label>
            <div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm">
              <input @change="uploadImage('brand_logo', $event.target.files[0]); validate()" type="file" name="brand_logo" id="brand_logo" :class="classes" class="focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 block w-full py-3 px-4 sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
            </div>
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
          </validation-provider>
        </div>

        <div>
          <validation-provider
            name="brand_favicon"
            rules="mimes:image/jpeg,image/png"
            v-slot="{ errors, classes, validate }"
          >
            <label for="brand_favicon" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 mb-2">
              Brand favicon <em>(PNG or JPG)</em>
            </label>
            <div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm">
              <input @change="uploadImage('brand_favicon', $event.target.files[0]); validate()" type="file" name="brand_favicon" id="brand_favicon" :class="classes" class="focus:ring-green-500 focus:border-green-500 block w-full py-3 px-4 sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
            </div>
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
          </validation-provider>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div class="flex justify-end">
        <button type="submit" class="group relative flex justify-center py-3 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500 disabled:opacity-20">
          <div class="inline-flex">
            <svg v-if="isSaving" class="animate-spin -ml-1 mr-3 h-4 w-4 text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <circle class="opacity-25" cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="4"></circle>
              <path class="opacity-75" fill="currentColor" d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8V0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12h4zm2 5.291A7.962 7.962 0 014 12H0c0 3.042 1.135 5.824 3 7.938l3-2.647z"></path>
            </svg>
            Create brand
          </div>
        </button>
      </div>

      <Alert
        v-if="feedback.isShown"
        :message="feedback.message"
        :variant="feedback.variant" />

    </validation-observer>
  </form>
</validation-observer>
```

The following function runs:

```html
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'account',
  data () {
    return {
      isSaving: false,
      form: {
        brand: '',
        url: '',
        telephone: '',
        link_terms: '',
        link_privacy: '',
        brand_logo: null,
        brand_favicon: null,
        seo_description: '',
        text_marketing: '',
        text_promos: '',
        text_broker: '',
        text_footer_1: '',
        text_footer_2: '',
        text_credit_disclaimer: '',
        analytics_system_id: '',
        analytics_brand_id: ''
      },
      feedback: {
        message: '',
        variant: '',
        isShown: false
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {

    /*
    ** Create
    */
    create () {
      this.feedback.isShown = false
      this.isSaving = true

      this.$axios.post(`${this.$config.apiUrl}/api/brands`, this.form, {
        timeout: 30 * 1000
      }).then((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.$router.push('/account/brands/')
        }, 500)
      }).finally(() => {
        this.isSaving = false
      })
    },

    /*
    ** Select files to upload (file uploader)
    */
    uploadImage (model, file) {
      const form = new FormData()
      form.append(model, file, file.name)
      this.form[model] = form
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Which `form` should now contain everything associated with my image, but when adding an image, it shows as an empty object (see attached)

[image]

I've also tried a `JSON.stringify` before setting my model, no luck here either.

Comment: Did you tried this kind of thing? https://academind.com/tutorials/vue-image-upload Also, you need to keep in mind the [caveats for arrays](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) in Vue2. Try to set the state to a single state for debugging purposes.

Comment: Yes, tried that, I've created a `form` variable in my function, and done `form.append('image', file, file.name)` but when console logging `form`, it's empty, I need it to be added to my `form` request

Comment: Last time I worked on this, I maybe experienced something similar. What happens if you send the file over HTTP? Do you see the content in the request payload?

Comment: I can't send the images separatly though. They must be part of the `form` object in the screenshot in my original post. They will work if sent via http yes, but how do I couple the whole request with everything else?

Comment: Are you using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)? Last time I used it, worked well. Maybe give a read to [this one](https://javascript.info/formdata).

Comment: Okay, so I've expanded my description with more context and code. I have a big form, two fields are images, when a user submits the whole form I need the images to go with it. When a user selects an image I need to set the appropriate image `v-model` values in `form`, I cannot send them individually.

Answer (score 0):

`formData` object properties are all functions, thus it is rendered in template as an empty object. In order, to display formData content in template you have to call one of its prototype function, and display its results.

```html
<div v-for="item in form.brand_logo.values()">
  {{ item }} 
</div>
```

As you can see in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-joliot-wwwug?file=/src/App.vue), after selecting a file, it is displayed in template as well as in console.

Since I've simplified a lot your code, and let only the formData stuff, maybe you should create a reproducible example.

Comment: Sure, but then if this is the case, why (when I submit my form) is it empty? My backend, Laravel even says it's empty here too when I log the value

Comment: One problem could be the incorrect content-type header. when posting with axios, it will infer the content-type from post data. In your case it will be application/json, since form is an object, and the multipart content will be left out. I think you should try to make all your `form` object into a formData object, or split the request, and send files separately. You cannot mix json and multipart request body.